# How to get app.js to call external package

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, passenger

Just starting out.
Hosting service is using Passenger, so app.js needs to be in one place to be recognized.

Redux wants to create self-contained folders with all the files.

How do I get the app.js to point into the build folder and stay up to date as things change?
folder format:

```
app.js
my-app/build/index.html
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to reconfigure Passenger (through the .htaccess file) to point to a different location.

```
PassengerStartupFile file_path
```